# How To Estimate Parameters In A Linear Regression Graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, linear-regression

I'm in the beginning of my machine learning course and I'm stuck at a quiz. A set of questions are setup like the following...

[Linear Regression Graph (Quadratic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxC5.jpg)

Possible answers are (Select all that apply):

**w0**

**w1**

**w2**

**None of the above**

It won't let me embed images yet so you have to click the link to see it. I'm faced with a set of the same question, each using a differently positioned line in the graph. I've received the following advice...

> Let's say f(x) = x, if you plot a graph with x as horizontal line and
>   f(x) as vertical line, what you get is 45º line start at (0,0). The
>   result is because when x=1, f(x)=1. so all the points will be
>   (0,0),(1,1),(2,2)...
>
> Let's say f(x)= 2+x, you still get the same 45º line except the
>   position of the line move up by 2 unit[(0,2),(1,3),(2,4),...], because
>   if x=0, f(x)= 2+0, and so on. Now if we swap '2' with variable, like
>   this f(x) = a +x, a will be the factor to decide on the position of
>   the line(the video say something about the position at around
>   1:50˜ish).
>
> Lat's say f(x)=2x, if you plot it into graph you will get
>   [(0,0),(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),...]. It is still a straight line but the
>   degree of the slanting line is different now. So same case, if swap
>   '2' with variable into f(x)=bx, b will be the factor of the slant.
>
> Let's say f(x)=xˆ2(square), you will get curve line(google quadratic).
>   simply plot the graph you will get
>   [(0,0),(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),...]. So when there is s curve line,
>   that means there must be some ˆ2 somewhere in the formula.
>   Additionally f(x)= xˆ2 can also be f(x)= 1*(xˆ2), and again if we swap
>   '1' with variable, we will get f(x)= c*(xˆ2).
>
> The last critical point is 0. so anything multiply 0 will be 0.
>
> This is as far as I can explain. Now, try to put everything together
>   and you will see what how the formula related to the graph.

Here's another tip I received...

> First off, completely ignore the blue dots, they're just noise.
>   Concentrate on the green line.
>
> Basically it's asking you how to produce that green line/curve.
>
> So the green line is plotted with an x and y values. The x value is
>   always the value going along the vertical axis (0, 1, 2, 3, etc). And
>   the y is the answer to the equation f(x) = etc.
>
> Looking at the equation we need to figure out whether to set w0 and/or
>   w1 and/or w2 to 0. As each one controls how the green line is drawn.
>
> I worked something like this if x = 0, which of the w values would I
>   need to set to 0 to get the starting point. Then I asked the question,
>   which w value would I need to set to 0 to draw either a straight line,
>   or curved line.

But I'm still having trouble understanding how 0 is fitted to w0, w1,or w2. The tips I've gotten don't seem to explain it to the level of detail that makes it intuitive enough for me. I have to get past this though. If I could just get past this initial point I shouldn't have a problem with the rest of my regression work.

Any help in clarifying every aspect of this problem (In simplified terms) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find simple explanation? I'm taking a same course on Coursera and struggling bit to fully understand. In my mind, the key is unique characteristic of each parameters, and determining which parameter is off when compared to the end result(given plot/graph): `f(x) = w0` is linear `f(x) = w1*x` is linear but more steep `f(x) = w2*(x^2)` is a curve This is as far as i've gotten and i'm interested in more detailed explanation

Comment: Thanks for the adding the advises you received,  it cleared all the related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The curve is a
straight line of non-zero slope,
so that
$w2=0$ since there is
no quadratic term,
and $w1 \ne 0$
since $w1$ is the slope.

Since the line does not
pass through the origin,
$w0 \ne 0$,